# How to restrict loading data based on some criteria using sql loader in oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a data file (.csv) which contains 10lacs records. I am uploading file data into my table TBL_UPLOADED_DATA using oracle SQL LOADER and control file concept.

I am able to upload all the data form the file to table smoothly without any issues.

Now my requirement is i want to upload only relavant data based on some criteria.

for example i have table EMPLOYEE and its columns are EMPID,EMPNAME,REMARKS,EMPSTATUS

i have a datafile with employee data that i need to upload into EMPLOYEE table.
here i want restrict some data that should not upload into EMPLOYEE table using sql loader. Assume restriction criteria is like REMARKS should not contain 'NO' and EMPSTATUS should not contain '00'.

how can i implement this. Please suggest what changes to be done in control files.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the `WHEN` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_control_file.htm#SUTIL1115) to choose to include or exclude a record based on some logic, but you can only use the `=`, `!=` and `<>` operators, so it won't do quite what you need. If your status field is two characters then you can enforce that part with:

```
...
INTO TABLE employee
WHEN (EMPSTATUS != '00')
FIELDS ...
```

... and then a record with `00` as the last field will be rejected, with the log showing something like:

```
  1 Row not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
```

And you could use the same method to reject a record where the remarks are just `'NO'` - where that is the entire content of the field:

```
WHEN (REMARKS != 'NO') AND (EMPSTATUS != '00')
```

... but not where it is a longer value that contains `NO`. It isn't entirely clear which you want.

But you can't use `like` or a function like `instr` or a regular expression to be more selective. If you need something more advanced you'll need to load the data into a staging table, or use [an external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL999) instead of SQL*Loader, and then selectively insert into your real table based on those conditions.